# An "incomplete" tiling?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, tiling, perfect-matchings

Given an $m\times n$ chess board, we place $p$ $2\times 1$ dominoes on the board so that they don't overlap. How many ways can we place them?

When each square of the board is covered by a domino this is the well-known tiling problem. Is there any research on the case where $p$ is small such that we have to leave some empty squares on the board?

Comment: These are still matchings (just not perfect matchings) of the corresponding graph. They are certainly studied, but less is known in general than for the case of perfect matchings.

Comment: There are also called *packings*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we sum over all $p$, then we obtain the number of monomer-dimer tilings of an $m\times n$ chessboard. This number is known to be #P-complete and hence very likely computationally intractable. For a reference, see citation [7] of the paper by Yong Kung [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610690).

Comment: That paper by Jerrum shows only that the problem is #P-complete for an arbitrary planar graph, which doesn't automatically imply that the problem is #P-complete when restricted to rectangles.

Comment: @TimothyChow: well also, at any rate, the original question was about fixing some small $p$ and asking how many matchings use exactly $p$ edges. For $p$ *fixed* we should be able to write this as a function of $m$ and $n$ which I'm guessing has a rational generating function.

Comment: @SamHopkins Good point about fixed $p$. If both $p$ and $m$ are fixed then I can believe that there is a rational generating function, but if only $p$ is fixed then I don't immediately see how to proceed. If you can figure this out then I think it would be worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're hoping for a nice formula, or for a fast algorithm that gives you the number exactly, then you're probably out of luck.

You're asking for the coefficients of the [matching polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_polynomial) of a grid graph.  As mentioned in [Richard Stanley's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442778/), it was shown by Jerrum ([Two-Dimensional Monomer-Dimer Systems
are Computationally Intractable](https://web.archive.org/web/20210921023339/http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~mj/papers/StatPhys.pdf), *J. Stat. Phys.* 48 (1987)) that this computational problem is $\mathsf{\#P}$-complete for planar graphs. That doesn't quite prove that the problem is $\mathsf{\#P}$-complete for grid graphs, but it seems unlikely that grid graphs are special enough to admit a fast algorithm.

On the other hand, planar graphs are quite friendly when it comes to [fixed-parameter tractability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#FPT).  In particular, if you fix $m$, then $m\times n$ grid graphs have [bounded treewidth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63068) (in fact, treewidth $m$), and a large class of computational problems on planar graphs with bounded treewidth (including this one) are fixed-parameter tractable.  See for example [On the fixed parameter complexity of graph enumeration
problems definable in monadic second-order logic](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810182723/https://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Textes1/BC-Makowsky-Rotics(2001).pdf), by B. Courcelle, J.A. Makowsky, and U. Rotics.

If you're satisfied with *approximate* counting, then the news is a bit better. The famous paper by Jerrum and Sinclair on [Approximating the permanent](https://web.archive.org/web/20170922034813id_/https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/perm.pdf) gives a [FPRAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme#Randomized) for this problem (see Corollary 4.4).